GA4 events not sending
I'm developing a website with Wordpress/WooCommerce. For Google Analytics I use Google SiteKit WP plugin, and I'm using directly GA4 (not Google Tag Manager) to track common and custom events. I encountered in an issue with thank-you-page where user is redirected after payment.
GA4 events (neither common like page_view, nor custom events) are not sending when user is redirected from payment service to thank you page. If I copy the url of thank-you page and paste it in new browser tab - everything is perfectly tracking. The payment service is Yoomoney. I have no clue what's wrong with this redirect and I'll be appreciate for any help here.
I'm looking in Network tab in browser and I see that response for event collection request is 204 (No Content), so this is not an issue in my code, but something on Google side I suppose.

My first guess here would be that it is a cookie-related issue. GA4 sets some cookies under your domain, and I am guessing it probably can't properly track, if those are missing. And in this particular scenario, where another site redirects back to yours, they would be missing, if they were not set with an appropriate SAMESITE value to begin with. (But I couldn't tell you if GA offers any option to influence that value for the cookies it sets.)
